# xcode running always, doesn't reach finished

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a basic Hello World app.
After it is compiled the toolbar has "Running  on " forever.

[image]

How can I get it to a "Finished" state?

Comment: This means it's working. Xcode will say this while your app is running in the simulator(as it appears to be). Apps will run until a user decides to kill them (or they crash). Congrats! you have a nice Hello World app :)

Comment: So, in that case and with what I have observed, simulator is always or mostly in running state, unless and until the user manually tries to stop it. Don't you think it is in bit contrast with other programming languages. I'm a beginner to this . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just because you chose Run instead of Build

In the main menu, press Product -> Build (CMD+B)

That will just compile your code, and tell you when it's "Finished"

But keep in mind that Run (CMD+R, or the Play button), does a Build first before it runs your application.  As long as your application is running, Xcode will tell you that it is "running"